# Retrofit2 validar usuario

Tags: php, android, retrofit

Estoy creando una app que consume datos de un servidor con Retrofit2. Las consultas Get i Post las tengo creadas y me funcionan perfectamente.

```
    @GET("baseclientes.php")
    Call<ArrayList<NClientes>> NClientes();
```

El problema viene cuando quiero validar que el usuario que esta consumiendo los datos tenga permisos. La idea es que el usario guarde nombre y contraseña y el servidor con php comprueve si tiene permisos.

He estado buscando ejemplos y tutoriales y al final he visto que una solución es usar un interceptor. He modificado mi API para añadir el interceptor pero no sé como trabajar los datos que llegan al servidor con php. La verdad es que soy muy novato en el uso de Retrofit.

```
  static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();

        Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder().header("Authorization",
                Credentials.basic("Usuario", "contraseña"));

        Request newRequest = builder.build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }

}).build();

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.miweb.com/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getApi(){
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Con debug veo que se crea el header. Pero al crear el fichero php no se como recibir los datos del header. He provado con esto pero no va...

```
 $header = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_decode($username . ':' . $password);
```

Alguna idea? Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues despues de mucho googlear he encontrado esta solucion que publico por si alguien le puede servir.

Para trabajar con el header solo basta con utilizar las variables de php:

```
  $user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
  $pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
```

A partir de aquí se puede confirmar si el usuario esta autorizado o no.